# How to save a stream to a file that would constantly change over time to have the right duration?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

How can I save a `ffmpeg` stream to a file that would contain the last 10 minutes of the stream and would constantly change over time to have this duration?

Comment: Are you asking for an output file that acts as a FIFO buffer?

Comment: Yes. I want the file to contain the last 10 minutes of the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Computers don't let you delete from the start of a file, so every time you trim video away, would required the file to be completely re written. Not a great idea. It would be better use some a fragmented format like HLS or DASH, and delete old fragments.